# get list of files from google drive using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api

Here is the code that i have tried all code goes good but when it comes under this function
'function makeRequest() {' then code does not execute and stops I thinks there is problem in response this function gets

```
   <html>
  <head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  var CLIENT_ID = '988680082729-    gudaete5nph93lq1sma15pb9cevi686r.apps.googleusercontent.com';
    var API_KEY = 'AIzaSyDPC8gi0zrOFBQmxfgh7rXPU8EQDPe5w-Y';
    var SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive';

  function handleClientLoad() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey(API_KEY);
    window.setTimeout(checkAuth,1);
  }

   function checkAuth() {
    var options = {
        client_id: CLIENT_ID,
        scope: SCOPES,
        immediate: true
    };
    gapi.auth.authorize(options, handleAuthResult);
}

function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');

    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        authorizeButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        makeApiCall();
    } else {
        authorizeButton.style.visibility = '';
        authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
    }
}

function handleAuthClick(event) {
    var options = {
        client_id: CLIENT_ID,
        scope: SCOPES,
        immediate: false
    };
    gapi.auth.authorize(options, handleAuthResult);
    return false;
}

function makeApiCall() {  
    gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', makeRequest);   
}

function makeRequest() {
    var request = gapi.client.drive.files.list({'maxResults': 5 });
    request.execute(function(resp) {          
        for (i=0; i<resp.items.length; i++) {
            var titulo = resp.items[i].title;
            var fechaUpd = resp.items[i].modifiedDate;
               var userUpd = resp.items[i].lastModifyingUserName;
            var userEmbed = resp.items[i].embedLink;
        var userAltLink = resp.items[i].alternateLink;

        var fileInfo = document.createElement('li');
        fileInfo.appendChild(document.createTextNode('TITLE: ' + titulo + ' - LAST MODIF: ' + fechaUpd + ' - BY: ' + userUpd ));                
        document.getElementById('content').appendChild(fileInfo);
    }
});
```

}

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#authorize-button').on('click', handleAuthClick);
  $.getScript('//apis.google.com/js/api.js', function() {
    gapi.load('auth:client', handleClientLoad);
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="authorize-button">Authorize</button>
<div id="content">Files:</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your request will return an object that has when I request a file list, the items are within a result object that is in the response. Try looking for `resp.result.items` in your `makeRequest()` function.